# Confusion On Using Mootools And The 'This' Keyword

Tags: javascript, this, mootools, mootools-events

I am trying to assign an event handler to a class I have created in Mootools but I cannot seem to access any of the variables that I created for the class. Like so:

```
var newPerson = new Class({
initialize: function(name)
{
    this.firstName = name;
    //-------Creating Div----------//
              ...........
    //--------Created Div----------//
    $(this.newDiv.id).click(function()
    {
        alert("clicked");
    };
 };
```

Now when I change the function to alert the objects assigned name `alert(this.firstName);` it doesn't access them and I can't figure out why.

Could anyone point my in the right direction?

Comment: you seem to use an odd mix of mootools + jquery. your class is mootools but dom events are jquery. seems unclean - you should stick to mootools code in the class throughout if possible. if classes is all you use mootools for, then just grab http://www.moo4q.com/ - mootools classes for jquery. pointy's answer for keeping a reference will work fine. if you want to point the click event to a class method (cleaner), then you can `this.newdiv.addEvent("click", this.handleClick.bind(this))` in native mootools.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the "initialize" function, add a variable declaration:

```
var thisObj = this;
```

Now, in your handler, you should be able to do:

```
alert(thisObj.firstName);
```

By stashing `this` as it stood when the "initialize" function began, you provide a way for the "click" handler to get at the original object. In the handler, `this` will refer to the DOM element involved with the event. (I'm actually guessing about that, because I'm not really familiar with MooTools.)

Comment: that's correct, scope will be the `event.target` element, unless you use `function.bind()` - careful with `$()` returning jquery tho. `$(this.newDiv).click(function() { ... }.bind(this));` will also work fine.

Comment: @Dimitar - The object referenced by the `this` keyword is not scope, they are entirely different things.

Comment: yes, agreed, this is just a context object pointer that will likely be either the global object (window), the class instance or an element pointer here. since it's a function, it gets a scope chain dependent on context and `this` is not directly related as vars canbe in the scope chain that have nothing to do with it. cheers